# Between 8G and 1TB - what is there?

Tags: storage

Currently, one can buy 8G DL DVDs for storage ($0.33 per Gig), and external 1TB USB HDs as another option ($0.10 per Gig.)   Is there a midrange technology, say 500G or so, perhaps tape-drives in a useful price-range for the consumer?

Comment: What are looking to store? Taps are good for some things, DVD's are good for others, External drives another, etc.

Comment: Althought, if it's a matter of storage for personal needs (home storage), I'd just go and buy a usb 500 gb external disc (they comes at about 50-90$ depending on the manufacturer, and are more then enought for anything one might need in non extreme circumstances).

Comment: price comparisons make this too localized for this site -- in 6 months the prices will be different.  if we can keep most of the price talk to generalities it might be ok.

Comment: ~quack - Prices per gb, don't differ *that* much for it to be localized. They are mostly a matter of production price ... and although prices differ along the world, the relative ratios between different storage means remain the same.

Comment: @Idigas - yeah, i'm more concerned with the localized-in-time aspect -- 2+ years from now all the $/GB we quote here will be irrelevant and outdated.

Comment: @~quack - Yes, that stands. But as he's seeking an answer in regards to choise of technology (where only ratios matter), I think I'll let this one stand. You might be right in that he maybe should add, #$0.33 per Gig as of Jan 2010", but I don't think it's that important. For if one uses "localized" in regards to time, for closing, one might close all questions regarding hardware since the prices of hardware in IT industry have always been, and are in continuous drop as time goes by.

Comment: @Idigas: right, well, we're not a shopping site, so closing requests for hardware recommendations on a given budget may be coming, much like "where should i buy product X" questions are already closed.  but we're well offtopic now and can continue this on meta if necessary.

Comment: 4.7gb DVDs are a better deal than the DLs.

Comment: @~quack - no need. We agree on too many things already for it to be "interesting" ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous options in between, yes (including tape drives).

1. [Blu ray discs](http://www.pctechguide.com/02Storage.htm) (BD-R/BD-RW).  For *optical* storage, this is the next level up from DVD-DL.
2. *Flash storage* a.k.a. *SSD*.  Cheap in the [8GB-USB-thumb-drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive) form, expensive in the [64GB-SATA-SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) form.  Prices will continue to fall, capacities will continue to increase.
3. [*HDDs*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive).  A stack of fast-spinning platters holding magnetic data inside a sealed metal box.  The bigger they are, the cheaper they come.  See the table under ["Capacity and access speed"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Capacity_and_access_speed) for a full listing of form factors and maximum platter capacity; here's a few of the current popular sizes:

   1. *1.8"* -- teensy.  3 platters, 320GB.
   2. *2.5"* -- standard laptop size.  3 platters, 1TB.
   3. *3.5"* -- standard desktop size.  5 platters, 2TB.

You mentioned [tape drives](http://www.superwarehouse.com/HP_StorageWorks_DAT_160_USB_External_Tape_Drive/Q1581SB/p/1517415). Althought not so popular amongst home users, they've always been there and used. I know some people who swear on them when it comes to backup. Not so cheap nowadays thought.

A general article on backup solutions [here](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20091212150931591/Tape.html).

Comment: ~quack - 'my gratitude for this very nice edit :)

Comment: yw!  i just thought you were missing a couple of things there.  :)

Comment: is ssd's for storage a good idea? i thought they were as reliable as thumb drives (not such a good idea for long term storage)